# Replacing string by numpy array in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
A, B
34, "1.0, 2.0"
24, "3.0, 4.0"
```

I'm reading the file using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

What I need to do is to replace the strings by numpy arrays:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        df['B'][index] = np.fromstring(df['B'][index], sep=',')
```

However, it raises the error `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`. However, the numpy arrays are being correctly created.

I need all value in B to be of type `numpy.ndarray`.

Edit:
I tried replacing df by row in the code.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['flux'] = np.fromstring(row['flux'][index][1:-1], sep=',')
```

And no error is raised, but the type of the variables doesn't change and the DataFrame still contains strings.

Comment: when you use `df['B'][index]` you first create a view (`df['B']`) which then update at the given index. When updating a view, the underlying dataframe (typically) doesn't get updates. If you index only once, you should get that problem: `df.loc[index, 'B'] = ...`. Read more in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply to change to that format:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x, sep=','))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `converters` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for convert to numpy array:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

temp='''A,B
34,"1.0, 2.0"
24,"3.0, 4.0"'''
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), converters={'B':lambda x: np.fromstring(x, sep=',')})

print (df)
    A           B
0  34  [1.0, 2.0]
1  24  [3.0, 4.0]
```